# How to preprocessing data of a game

Tags: data-mining, k-means

I have a table of users' scores like this:

```
user_id  score duration_of_per_play  start_date
  1        56    313                 2018-01-09
  2        14    560                 2018-08-01
  3        56    313                 2018-01-09
  4        14    560                 2018-08-01
```

....

now I want to use `k-means` algorithm the to cluster of users.
just I know that I haven't `Missing Values` and `outliers`.

but I don't know:

1. what is the next step?
2. do I need to `centering` data?